# Create multiple forms in a html table

Tags: php, mysql, html

I've got a MySQL database and a table called courses.  I would like to show the records of this table within an html table, but I would also like to edit them with a submit button at the end.

I know this has been asked before, but I'm still struggling with how I should properly proceed.

I currently have:

```
<tbody>
    <?php
        foreach ($db->getResultSet() as $row) {
            extract($row);
            ?>
            <tr>
                <form id="myTable" name="editrecord" action="course.php" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="code" value="<?php echo $code; ?>" /><!--PrimaryKey-->
                    <td><?php echo $code; ?></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="desc" value="<?php echo $desc; ?>" /></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="Edit" value="Edit!" /></td>
                </form>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
    ?>
</tbody>
```

Now this seems to work fine.  However I'm aware that `<form>` should not be inside `<tr>` or anywhere else other that `<td>`

I'm aware I could use various divs and set display properties to table layout etc. however I'd like to avoid this as I am using pre-made javascript that can sort and filter data which requires me to use `<table>`

I also tried a for loop outside the table to create 1 form per record and use the primary key as the form's id.  Then proceed with `echo "<td><input form='$code' ...`.  But this doesn't work in Explorer

What is the correct way to implement something like this?

Comment: `<form>` cannot be child of `<table>`.

Comment: `<input form='$code'` variables do not get parsed in single quotes.

Comment: If you insist on using the tables, you can simply put that data within divs and use javascript to detect the `save` button and dynamically create the form.

Comment: I just typed that code as a quick example of what I've tried. I've edited it to make it clearer. I know form can't be a child of table.  I'm wanting to know what's the correct way to code the above example.

Comment: I would suggest looping the course records out in an unordered list <UL> with <LI> elements then style divs/spans to contain your forms and data. You'll be able to modify the standard list and list item styling etc with CSS.

Comment: You might just do it as one form, and name the fields name1, code1, desc1, etc. Use the $x in your loop to create the field, so e.g. `<input name="name<?=$x?>"> ... <input name="code<?=$x?>"> ...` Or you could use the rowid, or the "code" if it's unique, etc.